# JBehave Tabular Parameter Issue

Tags: bdd, jbehave

I have a step with a tabular parameter "flightDate". The thing is that the placeholder isn't replaced by a real value when it occurrs in string mapped to "flight" which happens to be in JSON. Any suggestions on how I could get ALL occurences of flightDate to be substituted?

Step:

```java
@When("I book flight on <flightDate> where flight matches {$flight}")
public void bookTransaction(@Named("flightDate") Date flightDate, 
                            @Named("flight") Flight flight) {
}
```

Story:

```java
Given ...
When I book flight on <flightDate> where flight matches {
    flightDate: <flightDate>,
    ...
}
Then ...

|flightDate|
|2013-07-26|
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use <flightDate> in the Examples table.